# Can I make a nation of werewolves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I've reached the point in the Bloodmoon expansion where you can become infected with lycanthropy. After looking up the varying effects of being a werewolf I found this information about the werewolf's bite on [this wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf_(Bloodmoon)) that I found interesting.

> **Bite**: A bite from a werewolf is infectious and will turn any creature into a were-creature (wolf, boar etc.). undead are immune to it, but will spread it.

I'm not sure if this applies to all werewolves, just certain werewolves, or just me.

What I'm wondering is: **Is this something I can use if I become a werewolf and can I use it to convert the entire** (or majority at least, need to leave some to eat) **population of Vvardenfell into werewolves?**

Comment: "(or majority at least, need to leave some to eat)" Thinking ahead smart thinking. Yeah need to think of the armys food. But that choked me up I am sorry.

Comment: "undead are immune to it, but will spread it."  Sounds like it wouldn't just be you then...

Comment: atleast into were-creatures^^ Try it out and answer it here for yourself i'd like to know what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Almost everything on that page is inaccurate. Generally werewolves are treated like NPCS instead of creatures and generally do not have captured souls (though some end up being treated like creatures and do have petty souls). Daedric armor has no effect on werewolves (besides the high armor rating), and daedric weapons do not get the bonus double damage that silver weapons (and the Mace of Aevar Stone-Singer) do. See the UESP for more accurate information of lycanthropy in  Morrowind.

Comment: Well so much for my plans of world domination...